# MYSQL - order by indexed column

Tags: mysql

I have this table with 500,000 rows:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `listings` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `source_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `cat_id` mediumint(5) NOT NULL,
  `title` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  `views_point` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `publishedon_hourly` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `views_point` (`views_point`),
  KEY `listings` (`publishedon_hourly`,`published`,`cat_id`,`source_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=FIXED AUTO_INCREMENT=365513 ;
```

I want to make a query like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM listings
WHERE (`publishedon_hourly`
    BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP( '2015-09-5 12:00:00' )
    AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP( '2015-10-5 12:00:00' ) ) 
AND ( published =1 ) 
AND cat_id IN ( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 )
ORDER BY views_point DESC
LIMIT 10
```

This query sometimes works exactly as I want ([see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32952051/mysql-indexing-and-using-filesort/32952266)), but according to some opinions, this is incorrect. I searched the web for solutions and found these:

http://venublog.com/2007/11/29/mysql-how-to-avoid-filesort/
http://www.getsymphony.com/discuss/issues/view/657/

I added an index on `views_point` then tried this query:

```
select t1.* 
from  listings t1 
left outer join  listings t2 on (t1.views_point=t2.views_point) 
order by t1.views_point 
limit 10
```

This is the explain:

[image]

but I cannot add this condition:

```
`publishedon_hourly` 
    BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP( '2015-09-5 12:00:00' ) 
    AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP( '2015-09-5 12:00:00' )
AND ( published =1 ) 
AND cat_id = 5
```

I don't know, which one should I assign to (t1 or t2)?

On the other hand what about this way:

```
SELECT *
FROM listings
WHERE (`publishedon_hourly` 
    BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP( '2015-09-5 00:00:00' ) 
    AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP( '2015-09-5 23:00:00' ))
AND (published =1)
and views_point is not null
ORDER BY views_point DESC limit 20
```

If neither one will be good, can any one tell me please how the big blogs get the posts by hits?

Answer (score 1):

When building an `INDEX`, start with the '=' columns in `WHERE`.  Then move on to *one* range:

```
INDEX(published, publishedon_hourly)  -- or
INDEX(published, cat_id, publishedon_hourly)
```

In newer versions of MySQL, the second choice *may* do a leapfrog game (with the `IN`) to be more efficient than in older versions.  Give it a try.

[My cookbook](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql).

You could also give it this one

```
INDEX(published, views_point)
```

but that is risky -- It will be fast ood if 20 desired rows show up with high values of `views_point`, but it will be slow otherwise.  The Optimizer is not smart enough to always choose correctly between handing the `ORDER BY` versus handling the `WHERE`.

(As a side note... Did you want the extra noon?  `BETWEEN`..`AND` is *inclusive*.)